# Prove the inequality $\left(1+\frac{1}{a_1(1+a_1)}\right)...\left(1+\frac{1}{a_k(1+a_k)}\right)\ge\left(1+\frac{1}{p(1+p)}\right)^k$

Tags: inequality, fractions, substitution, jensen-inequality, tangent-line-method

> Let $a_1, a_2,...,a_k$ are any positive real numbers. Prove the inequality
> $$\left(1+\frac{1}{a_1(1+a_1)}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{a_2(1+a_2)}\right)...\left(1+\frac{1}{a_k(1+a_k)}\right)\ge$$
> $$\ge\left(1+\frac{1}{p(1+p)}\right)^k$$
> where $\sqrt[k]{a_1a_2...a_k}=p$.

#### My work so far:

I used Jensen's inequality.

Let $f(x)=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x(1+x)}\right)$. If $x\ge0$ then $f''(x)\ge0$. Then
$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{a_1(1+a_1)}\right)+...+\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{a_k(1+a_k)}\right)\ge k\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{q(1+q)}\right)$$
where $q=\frac{a_1+a_2+...a_k}{k}$.

Then $$\ln\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{a_1(1+a_1)}\right)...\left(1+\frac{1}{a_k(1+a_k)}\right)\right)\ge \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{q(1+q)}\right)^k$$
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{a_1(1+a_1)}\right)...\left(1+\frac{1}{a_k(1+a_k)}\right)\ge \left(1+\frac{1}{q(1+q)}\right)^k$$
But $$\left(1+\frac{1}{q(1+q)}\right)\not \ge\left(1+\frac{1}{p(1+p)}\right)$$

*I can not finish the proof of this inequality*

#### Addition 1:

[image]

#### Addition 2:

[image]

Comment: why do you not try a simple example at first, to find an idea? for e.g.$n=2$

Comment: Why do we expect it to be true?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second+derivative+of+ln(1+%2B+1+%2F+(e%5Ex+(1+%2B+e%5Ex)))

Comment: you can not apply ln to p. it does not make sense.

Comment: What is the source of the quote in Russian (e.g. the bibliographic details)?  Ideally, if a problem here comes from a published source, the full info for the source can be clearly included in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_i=\ln\frac{a_i}{p}.$

Thus, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i=0$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{i=1}^kf(x_i)\geq k\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{p(1+p)}\right),$$
where $$f(x)=\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{pe^x(1+pe^x)}\right).$$
But, $$f''(x)=\frac{p^2e^{2x}(4p^2e^{2x}+7pe^x+4)}{(pe^x+1)^2(p^2e^{2x}+pe^x+1)^2}>0.$$
Id est, by Jensen
$$\sum_{i=1}^kf(x_i)\geq kf\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^kx_i}{k}\right)=kf(0)=k\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{p(1+p)}\right).$$
Done!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Set $b_i = \ln(a_i)$ and apply Jensen's inequality to 
$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{e^x(1+e^x)}\right).$$